# cloudKit: CKSubscription error "This request requires an authenticated account""

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cloudkit

I'm testing my app with no authenticated iCloud accounts but I'm getting this error when to subscribe the device for notifications:

```
subscription  error<CKError 0x1700581e0: "Not Authenticated" (9/1002); "This request requires an authenticated account"; Retry after 3.0 seconds>
```

This is Ok but my question is how can check if the device is login to iCloud before try to run the CKSubscription code?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving CloudKit Record "Not Authenticated" (9/1002)" "This request requires an authenticated account""](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253415/saving-cloudkit-record-not-authenticated-9-1002-this-request-requires-an-a)

Comment: [See this asnwer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27315155/cloudkit-cksubscription-error-this-request-requires-an-authenticated-account/42473794#42473794), sometimes it can be stupid error.

Answer (score 11):

I ended up here searching for "cloudkit This request requires an authenticated account" on google. The problem for me was that I wasn't signed in to iCloud inside the simulator. I had kind of assumed I would be running under my development Apple ID automatically...

Comment: Everyone had super complicated answers and this was my problem. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the accountStatusWithCompletionHandler method on the container. If you want to use subscriptions, then it should return a status with a .hashValue of 1

```
    container = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
    container.accountStatusWithCompletionHandler({status, error in
        if (error != nil) { NSLog("Error = \(error.description)")}
        NSLog("Account status = \(status.hashValue) (0=CouldNotDetermine/1=Available/2=Restricted/3=NoAccount)")
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the Objective-C version:

```
     CKContainer *container = [CKContainer defaultContainer];
    [container accountStatusWithCompletionHandler:^(CKAccountStatus accountStatus, NSError *error)
    {
        if (((accountStatus == 3) || (accountStatus == 2)) && (!error))
        {
            NSLog(@" no error but status %ld",accountStatus);


//            typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, CKAccountStatus) {
//                /* An error occurred when getting the account status, consult the corresponding NSError */
//                CKAccountStatusCouldNotDetermine                   = 0,
//                /* The iCloud account credentials are available for this application */
//                CKAccountStatusAvailable                           = 1,
//                /* Parental Controls / Device Management has denied access to iCloud account credentials */
//                CKAccountStatusRestricted                          = 2,
//                /* No iCloud account is logged in on this device */
//                CKAccountStatusNoAccount                           = 3,
//            
//        }
        }


        if (error)
        {
             NSLog(@" accountStatus error %@",error);

        }
    } ];
```

Comment: Do not compare `accountStatus` against hardcoded integers. Compare against the enum values: `if (accountStatus == CKAccountStatusNoAccount`)`. This is much more readable and far less error prone.

Answer (score 0):

in swift 2 you compare status to

```
case CouldNotDetermine
case Available
case Restricted
case NoAccount
```